# From where I was sitting ... talk out of school ... getting pretty chummy with the money

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis, phrasal-verbs

From the film *Bad Teacher 2011*:

> **Amy Squirrel:** Umm...I happened to be pedalling past the 7th Grade car wash this Saturday.
>   **Wally:** Kill it! Can we talk about this later?
>   **Amy Squirrel:** Later we'll all die said the gator to the fly.
>   **Wally:** Fuckk!! What? - Just go.
>   **Amy Squirrel** Now, I don't want to speak out of school but ..from where I was sitting, I think ... It seemed like Miss Halsey was getting pretty chummy with the money.
>   **Wally:** Are you accusing Elizabeth of embezzling from the 7th grade car wash?

What does Amy Squirrel mean by "Now, I don't want to speak out of school 
but ..from where I was sitting, I think ... It seemed like Miss Halsey was getting pretty chummy with the money"? 
especially (from where i was sitting ) and ( I don't want to speak out of school)

Comment: This provides a little bit of context:  http://www.fmvmagazine.com/?p=2695

Answer (score 5):

"From where I was sitting" means more-or-less what it sounds: "from my perspective".

"From where I was sitting, it looked like the President was lying."  (It does not usually mean that literally, the placement of my seat gave me a better view, just that *my opinion on the matter* is such.)

"I don't want to speak out of school" is much more interesting.  "Speaking out of school", or more commonly, "telling tales out of school", means gossiping or revealing private matters.  It was a common saying as early as 1530, and appears in [*The Proverbs Of John Heywood*](http://www.archive.org/stream/proverbsofjohnhe00heywrich/proverbsofjohnhe00heywrich_djvu.txt) from 1546:

> She speaketh as shee would creepe into your bosome.
>   And when the meale mouth hath woon the bottome
>   Of your stomacke, then will the pickthanke it tell
>   To your most enimies you to buy and sell.
>   To tell tales out of schoole, that is her great lust.

A "pickthanke", the editor notes, is a person who 
tries to place people under small obligations by performing 
trivial services -- a word I will include in my vocabulary going forward.  I'm not sure exactly what the rest means, but you don't want some girl creepeing into your bosome, do you?

"Getting pretty chummy with the money" is not a fixed expression.  "Getty chummy" means "getting friendly" (*chum* being an old but still serviceable synonym for *friend*); "pretty" here just slang for "fairly" or "somewhat".  Amy is saying Elizabeth is handling the money as if it were her own.

"'Later we'll all die,' said the gator to the fly" is nonsense doggerel made up in the context of the movie.

Comment: That "4" in the third line of the quotation is simply a footnote reference, but it looks like IM Speak for "for." A note in another version of Heywood's Proverbs reports that a "pickthanke" is a toady.

Comment: Thanks, @SvenYargs, that made the passage slightly less mysterious.

Comment: @StoneyB -- everyone is a critic!  Updated.